# Get List of all users with the same physicalDeliveryOfficeName from AD in Visual C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap, directorysearcher

I'd like to search my active directory for all users that belong to a particular physicalDeliveryOfficeName (LDAP) and store them into an array of type SearchResult. Can I do this with a DirectorySearcher filter? Or is there a better approach?

I'm using asp.net, visual c#. Thanks!

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the DirectorySeacher class, your query could be

```
(&(objectClass=user)(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=Kalkutta))
```

where *objectClass=user* to get only user entries and *physicalDeliveryOfficeName=Kalkutta* is your query for an office.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://...");           
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
    {
         SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
         Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=Kalkutta))"
    };
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
SearchResultCollection result = search.FindAll();
foreach (SearchResult r in result)
     Response.Write(r.Properties["cn"][0]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!